# Two KendoUI windows parent and child stop propagation on keypress for current window Popup?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-events

I have two popUpEdit windows attached to two grids, one parent and one child.  I would like to add a `keyPress` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit or click the Update button.  The problem I am having now is that if I press Enter when the child Popup is open it propagates down to the parent container.  Here is my code so far.

`gridSumbitEnterAutoFocus` is called in each grid edit function so I thought `e.container` should be unique and the `keyPress` would be attached to each particular window.  I have also tried `stopPropagation` but I can't get that to work either.  Any help is always appreciated!

Ok some new information after debugging.  I disabled all of my `keypress` events, but the child popup still responds to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> `Keypress`.  I am not sure what it is doing exactly.  According to the firebug console it is not calling `saveChanges` or submitting, but both the child and parent windows close and I go back to my main grid after I hit enter when child Popup has focus.  I can hit enter on the parent Popup and nothing happens as expected.

```
function gridSumbitEnterAutoFocus(e) {

       e.container.keypress(function(event) {
        event.bubbles = false;
        event.stopPropagation(); debugger;
        //if the key press is ESC or Enter
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {//ESC
            e.sender.cancelChanges();
        } else if (event.keyCode === 13) {//ENTER
            event.bubbles = false;
            event.stopPropagation();
            // e.container.find('.k-grid-update').focus().click();
             e.sender.saveChanges();
        }
    });
    e.container.data('kendoWindow').bind('activate', function(e) {
        $('[autofocus]').focus()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out.  The enter key was responding to the browsers default submit action when form tags are on the page.  I don't need the form tags so I removed them.  I suppose there is a way to preventDefault action for submit, but removing the form tags worked fine. Now my keypress events are working with the proper popUpEdit window.  Thanks